# Printing text from Arrays

Tags: c

I can't seem to figure out why this is only printing the first position of the array. The file includes letters, punctuation, and spaces. It seems to be reading it all in correctly, just not printing out correctly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 520


char text[LENGTH];

void readDataFile();
void printScreen(char text[], int i);

int main() {

    readDataFile();
    return 0;
}



void readDataFile(){

    int i=0;
    FILE* fp = fopen("text.txt","r");
    while((fgets(&text[i], LENGTH, fp)) !=NULL){
        printScreen(&text[i], i);
        i++;
    }
  fclose(fp);
}

void printScreen(char text[],int i){

    printf("%c",text[i]);

}
```

These are the changes I have made that now print out only the last line of the text file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 520


char text[LENGTH];

void readDataFile();
void printScreen(char text[], int i);

int main() {

    readDataFile();
    return 0;
}



void readDataFile(){

    int i=0;
    FILE* fp = fopen("text.txt","r");
    while((fgets(text, LENGTH, fp)) !=NULL){
        printScreen(text, i);
        i++;
    }
  fclose(fp);
}

void printScreen(char text[],int i){

    printf("%s",text);

}
```

Comment: The second loop iteration causes a buffer overflow. `&text[1]` only has `LENGTH-1` characters of storage available.  It should be `&text[0]` each time, and `printScreen` should use `%s` and not use `i`.

Comment: So I made those changes and now it seems to only be printing out the last line of the text file

Comment: Show the changes you made

Comment: The updated code should work (it works for me too), maybe you are misinterpreting what you are seeing.  One thing to check might be what the line endings are on "text.txt". For example if you are running in unix but opening a Mac file that only has `\r` line endings then the output device might make them look each line is overwriting the previous line.  (In many terminals, `\r` means to back up to the start of the line but not move to the next line).  Try making a new text file on the same system that you are running the program on .

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest you another way to print your entire file ?

Replace your function readDataFile() with this :

```
void readDataFile(){

  int   nbread;
  int   fd;
  char  buf[2048];

  fd = open("text.txt", O_RDONLY);
  while ((nbread = read(fd, buf, 2048)) != 0)
    {
      buf[nbread] = '\0';
      printf("%s\n", buf);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add the library fcntl at the beginning of your file :

```
#include <fcntl.h>
```

Good luck ! :)

Answer (score 0):

fgets() takes in a line at a time and stores it in the string provided as the first argument. It looks like you are iterating through every line of the file and printing a single character from it. What you should try is:

```
while((fgets(text, LENGTH, fp)) !=NULL){
    printf("%s", text);
}
```

Comment: For some reason when I made your corrects it only prints the last line of the file

Comment: I'm really not sure what could be going on. When I run that code on my machine I get the desired output. can you post the exact code that you are compiling?